# Wortfolge "Ich habe meine Freundin am Wochenende ins Restaurant eingeladen."

Tags: word-order

In einem Lehrwerk steht

> Die Dativergänzung steht meistens vor der temporalen Angabe. Die
>   Akkusativergänzung steht hinter den temporalen, kausalen und modalen
>   Angaben und oder hinter der lokalen Angabe.

Folgender Satz wird als Beispiel angeführt:

> Ich habe ihnen täglich aus Heimweh sehnsüchtig mehrere SMS nach Hause
>   geschickt.

Wo sollte dann das direkte Objekt *meine Freundin* im folgenden Satz stehen?

> a) Ich habe meine Freundin am Wochenende ins Restaurant eingeladen.

oder

> b) Ich habe am Wochenende meine Freundin ins Restaurant eingeladen.

Ich neige zu (a), weil ich dachte, dass es etwas mit Thema-Rhema-Gliederung zu tun hat, wenn wir uns auf die wichtigere Information fokussieren und sie somit in den Vordergrund stellen. Aber nach der oben genannten Regel sollte dann (b) richtig sein. Stimmt es wirklich?

Comment: Was ist denn die wichtigere Information? Das kann sowohl die Freundin ("Willst du mit mir am WE essen gehen?" "Tut mir leid. Ich habe meine Freundin..."), als auch das Wochenende sein ("Deine Freundin sagt, du würdest sie nie zum Essen einladen." "Ich habe am Wochenende...").

Comment: Diese sogenannte "Tekamolo-Regel" ist nicht mehr als eine gewisse Tendenz in der Reihenfolge der Adverbiale. Das Beispiel ist zudem schlecht gewählt, denn je mehr Angaben man macht, desto unübersichtlicher wird es und desto ähnlicher klingen die verschiedenen Reihenfolgen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beide Varianten sind richtig. Die Wahl hängt davon ab:

- Wichtigeres (Informativeres, Überraschenderes) zuerst (vgl. TheAwfulLanguage)
- Kontext. Wenn mein Kollege gerade von seinem Wochenende erzählt hat, würde ich ohne Nachdenken (b) wählen.

Comment: Manchmal geht Wichtigeres aber ins Nachfeld. e.g. "Es sind 10 neue Leute gekommen".